# Reading changefeed within CosmosDB table with Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Azure and also to C# and I'm trying to get the changes within a particular table in my CosmosDB, I read lots of guides and etc but, not being able to make it works.

for now I have this:
[image]

Basically I'm reading the table and the output should be a folder\file in my BlobStorage.

My changeFeed function looks like this :

```
private static async Task<ChangeFeedProcessor> StartChangeFeedProcessorAsync(
    CosmosClient cosmosClient,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    string databaseName = configuration["ToDoList"];
    string sourceContainerName = configuration["Items"];
    string leaseContainerName = configuration["leases"];

    Container leaseContainer = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, leaseContainerName);
    ChangeFeedProcessor changeFeedProcessor = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, sourceContainerName)
        .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<ToDoItem>(processorName: "changeFeedFunction", onChangesDelegate: HandleChangesAsync)
            .WithInstanceName("consoleHost")
            .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
            .Build();

    Console.WriteLine("Starting Change Feed Processor...");
    await changeFeedProcessor.StartAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Change Feed Processor started.");
    return changeFeedProcessor;
}
```

apparently it's recognizing the change, but I keep getting errors :

```
Connected!
2021-09-13T12:56:31  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2021-09-13T12:57:31  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2021-09-13T12:58:23.635 [Information] Executing 'Functions.changeFeedFunction' (Reason='New changes on collection Items at 2021-09-13T12:58:23.6297440Z', Id=a5f07660-5827-47af-9460-38e1e8be2b0b)
2021-09-13T12:58:23.794 [Error] Function compilation errorMicrosoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException : Script compilation failed.at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 321at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32 attemptCount) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionLoader.cs : 55at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync(Boolean isInvocation) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.cs : 193
2021-09-13T12:58:24.099 [Error] run.csx(5,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CosmosClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:25.171 [Error] run.csx(6,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:25.476 [Error] run.csx(4,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ChangeFeedProcessor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:25.872 [Error] run.csx(25,58): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToDoItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:26.146 [Error] run.csx(25,77): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CancellationToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:26.442 [Error] run.csx(12,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Container' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:26.677 [Error] run.csx(13,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ChangeFeedProcessor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:26.908 [Error] run.csx(14,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToDoItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:27.305 [Error] run.csx(28,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ToDoItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-09-13T12:58:27.801 [Error] Executed 'Functions.changeFeedFunction' (Failed, Id=a5f07660-5827-47af-9460-38e1e8be2b0b, Duration=4066ms)Script compilation failed.
2021-09-13T12:59:31  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
```

I'm using this guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor

can someone give a help?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main topics here:

1. Azure Functions Trigger: If you want to use the Azure Functions Trigger, you do not need the Change Feed Processor, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-functions. You want to be writing something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=csharp
2. Change Feed Processor: CFP is a construct that you can use if you want to consume the Change Feed in your own compute (A VM, some background service, etc.) that is not Azure Functions, and the reason is, Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger already runs the Change Feed Processor for you when you declare the Trigger.

The error you are seeing is because you are mixing these 2 things, you have an Azure Function that is trying to then create a Change Feed Processor. The code you are using is referencing the Cosmos DB SDK V3 and you either are missing the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` nuget package or the `using` statements at the top of your file.

My recommendation would be, if you want to run on Azure Functions, then just use the Trigger, no need to start a CFP instance. CFP can be used in any other compute platform, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor#where-to-host-the-change-feed-processor

Comment: Hi Matias, really thanks for your reply and sorry about my delay, so you are saying that I don't need to have a Function(changeFeedFunction) and could simply use the Trigger(Azure Cosmos DB Input) in my case?

Comment: Hi Matias, I'm following the approach mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=csharp
But, nothing is happening when I insert a new item in the table
And sorry this is the first thing I'm developing in Azure

Comment: @gfernandes - The Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger and Change Feed Processor will work on SQL API accounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#supported-apis-and-client-sdks - Are you using a Table API Cosmos account? If yes, Change Feed is not supported there.

Comment: Hi @Matias Quaranta, I'm not sure but I think I'm using a table API Cosmos Account. What I'm trying to understand is the difference between Azure Functions Cosmos DB Trigger and Change Feed Processor, are we not talking about functions itself?

Comment: None of the alternatives will work on a Table API account, Table API does not support Change Feed so Change Feed Processor won't work, and Azure Functions Trigger won't work they are for SQL API accounts. Please check the link in my last comment. The difference between each is explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/read-change-feed#reading-change-feed-with-a-push-model. If you want to run on Functions, use the Trigger, not Change Feed Processor. Change Feed Processor is for when you have your own different compute (like a VM).